# SSRS report won't load in browser

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS, but have begun migrating our reports to that for my organization.  I have 3 reports set up at this time, but have run into a problem.  Viewing any of the reports in Report Builder works just fine, but viewing 2 of the 3 in IE (also tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera) is only sporadically successful.  Report server is set up on database server, and nothing in the queries being run would tax the system.

I know the security settings are correct, as I can access everything without permissions errors; I know the reports work, as I can freely use them in Report Builder and sometimes from the browser; and I am able to always access one of my three reports through the browser.  All have the same security, are in the same folder, and I have gone through the same steps to load each of them.  The only difference is that the one that always loads is much simpler than the other two as far as volume of data.

Now, to explain what I actually see when this happens.  I set my parameters, and click View Report, and the loading icon pops up for about 1/10th of a second, then disappears.  The toolbar does not appear, no data appears, and no error message is present.  Every once in a while, it all works perfectly.  Most of the time, only 1 of the 3 reports works.  I've tried without success to find this issue raised elsewhere -- my apologies if I missed it.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

*edit* details: SQL Server 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2008 R2, IE9 from a Windows 7 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the SSRS error log it may reveal more of the issue. Sounds like a processing error that was not gracefully handled. Inspect the file \SERVER\\MSRSXX.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles and find the current log file to view the exception. Depending on how the client is set up some errors may not show.